# How to getBoundingClientRect from a hidden element? (doesn't work on IE)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I've found a way to `getBoundingClientRect` from a hidden element: Make its `display` style to `initial` so the browser can calculate properly. Then hide instantly the element so it never shows up to the user.

But it doesn't work on IE. It always returns `0`.

How can I make this work on IE?

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#foo');

console.log('Element is hidden', element.getBoundingClientRect());

element.style.display = 'initial';
console.log('Element shows for little time', element.getBoundingClientRect());
element.style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="display: none;">Guess my size, I'm hidden !</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, IE doesn't support `initial` value ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)). So the assignment does nothing, and the element remains hidden, that's why you get 0 as a resulting height.

But even if it did, it wouldn't have worked the way you expected: `display: initial` sets the universal initial value for `display` for all the affected elements - that's `inline` both for `div`s and `span`s. Here's little [proof-of-concept](https://jsfiddle.net/256atrhj/) of this behaviour.

Instead you have to cache the original value of `display` by your own code before hiding it. Actually, that's exactly what jQuery and other popular frameworks do with their implementation of `.hide()`:

> The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ),
>   except that the value of the display property **is saved in jQuery's
>   data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value**.
>   If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown,
>   it will once again be displayed inline.

Comment: I made it work using `element.style.display = 'block';`

Answer (score 1):

This might answer the question indirectly - another option if you need to getBoundingClientRect() for a hidden element is to hide it in a different way (other than display:none). Setting color and/or background-color to transparent, for example.